# When is the generated $\sigma$-algebra of a Borel-measurable random variable complete?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a probability space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$, we say that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$ is *$\mu$-complete* provided that

$$
\text{if}\quad N\in\mathcal{E} \quad\text{with}\quad \mu(N) = 0, \quad\text{then also}\quad \tilde{N}\in\mathcal{E} \quad\text{for any } \ \tilde{N} \subseteq N.
$$

Let now $(F,\tau)$ be a Polish space and $X : E \rightarrow (F, \tau)$ be Borel-measurable (and assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is $\mu$-complete, if necessary).

Which (non-trivialising) conditions on $X$ guarantee that

$$
\text{the $X$-generated $\sigma$-algebra} \quad \sigma(X):=\sigma(X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\tau) \quad\text{is } \ \mu\text{-complete}\,?
$$

Comment: Do you have an example where it is complete?  Say non-trivial in the sense $\mu$ is continuous?    I suppose there is the case where $\sigma(X)$ itself is atomic because $X$ has countable range. Otherwise, I would think $\sigma(X)$ has power at most $\mathfrak c$, but a sigma-algebra complete for a continuous measure has power $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

Comment: @GEdgar I have no such example, no.